# Stored Procedure Help: Passing a Year as a parameter to get results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, parameters, datetime

I'm trying to basically input a year (not the entire date) to get back a set of results that will tell me the amount of things sold this year. I'm not sure how to go about doing this however. Below is an example of what I have down.

```
ALTER PROC OrderYear
(@OrderYear datetime)
AS

SELECT Orderdate as [Year],COUNT(SalesOrderID) as Count
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE @OrderYear=YEAR(OrderDate)
GROUP BY OrderDate

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
END

EXEC OrderYear '2005'
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to express the query predicate as a range, because a range is sargable:

```
SELECT Orderdate as [Year],COUNT(SalesOrderID) as Count
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE OrderDate >= @firstDayOfYear AND OrderDate <= @lastDayOfYear
GROUP BY OrderDate;
```

So the trick is to computer the `@firstDayOfYear` and `@lastDayOfYear` from a given year. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: or `OrderDate < @firstDayOfNextYear` to work with datetime as well.

Comment: @ypercube I thought that if it has a `GROUP BY OrderDate` it probably doesn't have time component, but you're right, using `<` would work for `date` *and* `datetime`

Answer (score -1):

The procedure are ok,  change the type of the input parameter:

```
ALTER PROC OrderYear
(@OrderYear int) 
AS
SELECT Orderdate as [Year],COUNT(SalesOrderID) as Count
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE @OrderYear=YEAR(OrderDate)
GROUP BY OrderDate
```

Comment: It may work but it won't be efficient. Applying functions to columns (usually) makes the conditions not sargable.

Comment: but are you sure that OrderDate is present on index? If not the last query is more fast.

Comment: Even without an index, why will it be faster? The `YEAR()` function will have to be called as many times as the rows in the table. With Remus' answer, no function calls at all (ok, maybe once to calculate the @firstDayOfYear and @lastDayOfYear.)